# Firebase Realtime database security rules for query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my app and on client side I run a query which is:

```
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child(`Posts`)
      .orderByChild('userID_DatePosted')
      .equalTo(userID + '_' + myDate)
      .once('value')
```

The myDate is a variable that I have stored it in on client side from previous interaction.
My security rule in the Firebase should look like something like below:

```
            ".read": 
              query.orderByChild == 'userID_DatePosted' &&
              query.equalTo == auth.uid + '_' + ANYDATE,
```

What do I need to enter instead of ANYDATE so any query that contains auth.uid with anything after '_ ' returns true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `query.equalTo` is a string value, you can use any [operations that work on a string](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#string_methods) in security rules.

For example:

```
query.equalTo.startsWith(auth.uid+'_')
```

I'm not entirely sure what `ANYDATE` is, but that you might be able to capture with a regular expression:

```
query.equalTo.matches(/_[0-9]+/)
```

And if needed you can combine the two conditions with an `&&`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was what I was looking for